# Do transient properties in grails effect memory usage of an application?

Tags: performance, grails, memory, transient, tcserver

I am using transient properties per domain class. Some of them have more than 10.

I am experiencing a very slow application. I started analysing it using tc server. the most part of loading time is consumed by rendering gsp-files.

is there any known issue on transient value that they consume more memory or slow the whole app? Do I have to replace them by normal properties and update values on Insert/Update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your transient properties are of type String, Integer, or similar, it is inconceivable that they would have a significant impact on application performance.

My intuition is that transient properties would incurr less overhead than persistent properties because they do not need to be persisted and read from the database, so converting them to persistent properties will likely only make things slightly worse.

Comment: This is what I would have assumed, but I wasn't sure enough to submit an answer :) +1